# Adding a "frequent changes" warning to certain tags

Tags: feature-request, tags

Recently I've come across situatens where answers on questions I asked years ago get commented with "not working for me". That happens especially in fields where technology changes frequently.

The Facebook API, for example, is known for that. It's quite likely that answers (especially those that contain code) that are perfectly valid when they are posted, become invalid after a certain amount of time because the API has changed meanwhile. I think that is also true for other API's and technology stacks.

*I wanted to include the question link for reference but it seems the commenter deleted their comment*

What I would like to suggest is a warning on questions with certain tags (for example API tags that are known to change frequently such as the Facebook API) to raise awareness that the answers posted on this questions might be invalidated by now.

Also the warning should only appear after a certain amount of time has passed.

Something like:

> The technology the question is about underlies frequent changes. Please consider that the answers posted on the question might be invalid or lead to unintended behavior before commenting or posting new answers.

I'm not an English native speaker so the above suggestion could certainly be refined.

Would there be any downsides of having such a warning? Or is it even redundant at all?